# Why does the column content say “Array”?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

[image: igot array wis]

I got this problem when I'm doing mysql that every time that I post pictures on the blog it will say to the database that I got array on image column. it is supposed to have the image that I inserted

Comment: What's the datatype of the `image` column?  What PHP code did the insert?  It sounds like you don't really have an image there, but a form of error message.

Answer (score 0):

It does have the image that you inserted. The database does not have a renderer that it can use to display the images. All files are stored as an array of bytes (binary format). You would need to extract the file using code and convert it to an image to be displayed. As it stands, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: How can I extract the file? and the picture that I put in wont show up to my blog.

Comment: You can get the bytes by just selecting the column. You will need to do convert it to an image in php, it cannot be done in SQL.